# Table with dynamic iterator

Tags: dynamic, list-manipulation

I would like to make a Table whose iterator has a dynamically updated endpoint, i.e.

```
Table[i,{i,1,Dynamic[n]}]
```

Is this possible? Here is the context:

```
n=1
SetterBar[Dynamic@n, Range[1, 10, 1]]
f[x_]:=Module[
         {y},
         y=Table[0,{i,1,Dynamic[n]+4}]
         For[ i=3,i<=Dynamic[n]+4,i++,
                y[[i]]=y[[i-1]]+2y[[i-2]]
         ]
       ]
y=f[Dynamic[x]]
```

I get the error

> ```
> Iterator {i,1,4+1} does not have appropriate bounds.
> ```

As another example of how I'd like to use this, here is fully functional code:

```
n=1;
Manipulate[Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString@i], {i, 1,Dynamic@n + 1}],
           {x1, 1, 10}, {x2, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: You need to think about where you place `Dynamic`. In this simple example you should place it outside of `Table`. If you wrap `Table` in something else, `Dynamic` might have to be moved even further away from `Table`. The idea is to make the *expression* dynamic, not just one variable. Without knowing what you are planning on using this for any answers that we can provide might not help you that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Pickett, you have to wrap `Dynamic` around the expression that is to be displayed. You also forgot to return a value from your function `f`. Here is a modification of your code that works:

```
Clear[f]

f[x_] := Module[{y},
  y = Table[0, {i, 1, n + 4}]; 
  For[i = 3, i <= n + 4, i++, y[[i]] = y[[i - 1]] + 2 y[[i - 2]]];
  y]

n = 1;
SetterBar[Dynamic@n, Range[1, 10, 1]]
```

[image: bar]

```
Dynamic[f[x]]
```

> $\{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\}$

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I was writing the Dynamics inside-out, or so to say - I also fixed the extra line I added to the question, thanks to you: Manipulate[
 Dynamic[Table[
   ToExpression["x" <> ToString@i], {i, 1,n + 1}]], {x1, 
  1, 10}, {x2, 1, 10}]